# Apply a vector-valued function to a vector. Result not as expected

Tags: r, vectorization

In Matloff's The Art of R programming, he uses the function below (`z12`) to demonstrate the use of a vector-valued function.

[image: vector-valued function]

My question is: When applying the function to `1:8`, why does it return `1 2 3 4 ... 1 4 9 16 ...` and not `1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9 ...`? After all, isn't `z^2` right next to `z` in the return statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `c()` is the concatenation operator. It joins two vectors end to end. You can do

```
c(1, 2)
# [1]  1  2
c(1:3, 9:11)
# [1]  1  2  3  9 10 11
```

So the function you've defined is running

```
c(1:8, (1:8)^2)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1  4  9 16 25 36 49 64
```

So the `c()` puts together the vectors after they have been extended. Not as the extension is happening.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I don't know why I expected the function to operate on single elements of the vector. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

We can change the function to

```
z12 <- function(z) c(rbind(z, z^2))
z12(x)
#[1]  1  1  2  4  3  9  4 16  5 25  6 36  7 49  8 64
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use `rep` and recycling.

```
zN <-  function(x) rep(x, each=2)^c(1:2)
```

Now, give it a try.

```
zN(1:8)
 [1]  1  1  2  4  3  9  4 16  5 25  6 36  7 49  8 64
```

Or, with the desired order

```
zN2 <-  function(x) x^rep(1:2, each=length(x))
zN2(1:8)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1  4  9 16 25 36 49 64
```